# mvc 3 dynamic Category Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Ok, I have read a bunch of articles, and I am still lost, so I figure I will put the question out here.

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown in my "posts" create view.  I would like to pull the selectList items from my Categories.sdf, which has a table called categories and two columns, "CategoryID" and "CategoryTitle".

I know I need to pull the items into the viewbag within by "postscontroller" so they can be passed to the view.  But I am not sure what this would look like.  Again, i'm new to MVC so if i sound like a dope, i apologize.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I need to pull the items into the viewbag within by "postscontroller"

Oh no, you don't need to do anything like that.

You could start by defining a view model:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Select a category")]
    [Required]
    public string SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

that you will populate in your controller:

```
public class PostsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PostViewModel();
        model.Categories = db.Categories.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.CategoryId,
            Text = c.CategoryName
        });
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then have a corresponding strongly typed view (`~/views/posts/index.cshtml`):

```
@model PostViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories, "-- select --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId)

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: So Since I already have a Post model set up, put that first block of code in there?

Comment: Yes, if you already have a view model you could use that view model.